# Get Form Data Using DLL Name

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

I am creating a tool on an application that opens some windows forms to get information from users, my tool should deal with these windows forms by itself without users' interactions.
I have initiated an event to get the opened form's process when it opens by the following code:

```
mgmtWtch = new ManagementEventWatcher("Select * From Win32_ProcessStartTrace");
mgmtWtch.EventArrived += WatchManagementEvent;
mgmtWtch.Start();
```

The shown window has OK button which i want to click, and i don't know how to make this action. while the parameter that i can get from this event is

> EventArrivedEventArgs e

my question is how can i click the OK button through this event handler?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at .Net's GUI automation API?

You'll want the **UIAutomationClient** and **UIAutomationTypes** assemblies.

I've used this API to drive installers, UIs during testing etc.

I found this link useful initially.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/04/08/10409196.aspx

e.g. assuming you have the parent window (i.e. the Form) for the button and you know the button's ID:

```
using System.Windows.Automation;
....
static AutomationElement FindById(AutomationElement root, string id, bool directChild)
{
    Assert(root != null, "Invalid input: ParentWindow element 'root' is null.");

    Condition conditions = new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.AutomationIdProperty, id);

    return root.FindFirst(directChild ? TreeScope.Children : TreeScope.Descendants, conditions);
}
....
AutomationElement button = FindById(containerWindow, id.ToString(), true);

InvokePattern invokePattern = null;
try
{
    invokePattern = button.GetCurrentPattern(InvokePattern.Pattern) as InvokePattern;
}
catch (InvalidOperationException)
{
    MessageBox.Show("The UI element named " + button.GetCurrentPropertyValue(AutomationElement.NameProperty) + " is not a button");

    return false;
}

invokePattern.Invoke();
```

If you don't know the button's ID but do know it's name i.e. the text on the button then replace `AutomationElement.AutomationIdProperty` with `AutomationElement.NameProperty` in `FindById` (and rename the method appropriately)

Assuming the button is in the top-level Form window and you know the title displayed in this Form window, the following code will get the button's parent window:

```
bool ignoreCase = true; // or false if preferred
Condition conditions = new PropertyCondition(
    AutomationElement.NameProperty,
    windowTitle,
    ignoreCase ? PropertyConditionFlags.IgnoreCase : PropertyConditionFlags.None
);

AutomationElement myForm =
    AutomationElement.RootElement.FindFirst(
        TreeScope.Children,
        conditions );
```

The Window Title can be retrieved from the process you already have via the process' MainWindowTitle property.

Comment: thanks for your reply, but i don't know even know the parent window name. so is there a way to get its name?

Comment: What do you mean by 'parent window name'? The title? What details of the Form app do you know?

Comment: e.g. if you have a System.Diagnostics.Process object for the Form's process you can get the Window title (caption) from the Process's MainWindowTitle property.